# Partial Conundrum in purrr

Tags: r, functional-programming, purrr

Hi I frequently find myself using `.fists = FALSE` argument in `purrr:partial`.
So today I decided to stop repeating myself and I tried to write a **partial** of `partial` itself:

```
backwards_partial <- partial(partial,.first = FALSE)
```

This function made me nervous rather quickly, because it is ambiguous as to how `.first = FALSE` will be used:

- as a default parameter of outputted function
- as argument of calling partial that will move pre-filled arguments to the back of in outputed function

I thought I could remedy this ambiguity by writing this:

```
backwards_partial <- lift_ld(lift_dl(partial),list(.first = FALSE))
```

But this failed and it does not seem elegant.

So my question is...
Is there a *correct way*(best practice, community standard) that I'm missing here?
If so what is it?
Otherwise how would you solve this problem?

EDIT:

I should mention my use case for having `backwards_partial`.
I am looking to pre-fill arguments of multiple functions that I will pass into `compose` which will pass results of past function into first argument, hence `.fists = FALSE` ensures that we are not overwriting pre-filled arguments.

Comment: I'd avoid the ambiguity entirely by employing a different package/method for creating a partial, either using an anonymous function or: `library(functional); new_partial <- Curry(purrr::partial, .first=FALSE)` (have not tested the result since I'm not clear what `.first` is actually supposed to accomplish)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way:

```
# copy function
backwards_partial <- purrr::partial
# change formals
formals(backwards_partial)[5] <- alist(.first = FALSE)
```

Let's test it:

```
partial(head,2)(1:5)
# Error in head.default(2, ...) : length(n) == 1L is not TRUE

partial(head,2,.first = FALSE)(1:5)
# [1] 1 2

backwards_partial(head,2)(1:5)
# [1] 1 2
```